# How to make a java Thread unstoppable without catching Throwable

Tags: java, multithreading, try-catch, infinite-loop, throwable

I want to make a thread unstoppable for some reason, what is the sonarcube compliant solution?
I have to catch Throwable but.

It says:
Catch Exception instead of Throwable.
Throwable and Error should not be caught

I cannot only catch Exceptions

Comment: You should listen to sonar, generally you can't recover from `Error` and it's subclasses. How do you handle `OutOfMemoryError` in a meaningful way,  for example?

Comment: I know what sonarcube says, Is there any way to do it in compliant way?

Comment: The compliant way is to not catch `Throwable`s. Or you can use `@SuppressWarnings("sonar code")` to suppress the check, if you are **very** confident in your handling.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of how to catch and rethrow exceptions to comply with the rule:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Your thread logic here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle specific exceptions if needed
            // Rethrow as unchecked exception or wrap and rethrow
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```